# What is this symbol in the notification bar mean?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notification-bar

What does this symbol on my galaxy grand duo running kitkat mean?

[image: symbol on the bar]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the entire notification bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the device is connected to a dock. You can find it described e.g. on [this Samsung support page](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/skp/faq/1046098) (scroll down to the last third, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> for "dock or cradle").

Comment: Thanks! I've integrated that with your answer post (note you can always [edit] your posts to adjust), followed by upvoting your answer (counter-balancing the downvote it meanwhile received). Cleaning up comments now, so don't wonder :)